# What do you call the two groove settings in a stapler?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Stapler anvils have two kind of grooves on the anvil that allow pins to close inwards and outwards?

What word/phrase is used to refer to these settings?

[image]

Comment: The normal one and the funny one.

Comment: Today I learned the, in retrospect, obvious, phrase "stapler anvil".

Comment: Well, today I learned that staplers even have such a setting.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Not all do, just most. I've found a handful of older ones that do not.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The two types are called **stapling** and **pinning**.

The **pinning** groove, also known as the **sheer setting** is used for papers/items that need to be fastened together temporarily, hence the outward bending of the staple. This method makes removal much easier than the normal **stapling** method, also known as the **reflexive setting**, which bends the staple inwards, causing a more permanent and harder to remove fastening.

[image: Both methods of stapling]

([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staple_(fastener)) & [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stapler))